# Display multiple attached document names in div tag and remove single documents on clicking them.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, file-upload

I have been trying to implement this functionality using JQuery that when files are uploaded using the input field I want to add div tags along with the file names above it. 
This is the code for the input field:

```
 <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" name="uploadBtn" title="Upload Button" multiple>
```

Here is the function that adds the div tag to the screen above it:

```
     function handleFileSelect(e) {

        if(!e.target.files) return;
           var data = new FormData(); 
            var files = e.target.files;
            for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            var f = files[i];
            data.append(f.name,f);
            console.log(f.name); 
            **$('#attachedFiles').append(
                 '<div class="row"><div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield justify-space mdl-textfield--file mdl-textfield--file-is-dirty has-placeholder is-upgraded" data-upgraded=",MaterialTextfield"><input class="mdl-textfield__input" placeholder="'+f.name+'" readonly="" type="text" title="Upload File"></input> <div class="mdl-button mdl-button--primary mdl-button--icon mdl-button--file">                                       <svg role="img" aria-labelledby="remove-attachment1" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"                                             width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">                                           <title id="remove-attachment1">Remove Attachment</title>                                           <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 16.538l-4.592-4.548 4.546-4.587-1.416-1.403-4.545 4.589-4.588-4.543-1.405 1.405 4.593 4.552-4.547 4.592 1.405 1.405 4.555-4.596 4.591 4.55 1.403-1.416z"></path>                                   </svg>                                     <input id="'+uploadFile[i]+  '" data-usage="' + f.name +  '"  title="Upload Button">                              </div>                                </div>                            </div>'
            );**

            }


    }
```

I am trying to add a function removeFiles so that when i click on the input field with id "uploadFile[i]" it should remove the file at position i. Also the function to remove the file should return the filename because I will be needing the filename to remove the file from the back-end using a rest api call.

I am trying to achieve this with the following code:

```
 var current = [];
                     for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {

                          current[i]= document.getElementById(uploadFile[i]);
                                current[i].addEventListener ("click", removeFunction, false);
                     }
```

But this doesnt work and the eventlistener is attached only to the first file that is attached. 
It would be great if someone could help me with this as I am struggling here.

Comment: Sorry, please provide more information. Like: where is `removeFunction`? Or a jsfiddle link to easy debug.

Comment: Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/rPaZQ/        using reset will help you for one. use of ,closest will find the nearest id "file" and  or you can set it to <form> as in example.

OR simply clear the value of input field http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/dAQVM/489/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="'+uploadFile[i]+  '" data-usage="' + f.name +  '"  title="Upload Button">
```

Please check this line of your code. you are declaring  the input id incorrect.
it should be " uploadFile " + i.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a really silly mistake on my end as I have not defined any uploadFile array and was trying to add its elements as the id.

Answer (score 1):

Your code provide don't have information to debug.

So, I provide a different method to resolve your problem.

The file list of HTML5 file input is readonly, so when trying to remove a file from it you won't be allowed.

What you need to do is maintain a separate array list (JSON array as per the example).

I have wrapped your X button with a div that hold the file index concatenated to a 'file_' string, and added an `onclick` function `removeLine(obj)` that accepts the element as an object.

I have also added a JSON array `finalFiles` in the global scope as well as moved the `inputFile` to the global scope.

When the file input changes, I am setting the JSON array with the selected files through :

```
$.each(this.files,function(idx,elm){
           finalFiles[idx]=elm;
        });
```

The function `removeLine` will flush the input file list to allow the same file selection again if the user removed the file by mistake, the function obtains the file index from the wrapper division id, removes the wrapper div then deletes the file from the JSON array.

```
function removeLine(obj)
    {
      inputFile.val('');
      var jqObj = $(obj);
      var container = jqObj.closest('div');
      var index = container.attr("id").split('_')[1];
      container.remove(); 

      delete finalFiles[index];
      //console.log(finalFiles);
    }
```

You can the maintain your files when the form submits and send them through AJAX post using FormData in a similar manner to [This Article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax).

```js
var dropZoneId = "drop-zone";
  var buttonId = "clickHere";
  var mouseOverClass = "mouse-over";
var dropZone = $("#" + dropZoneId);
 var inputFile = dropZone.find("input");
 var finalFiles = {};
$(function() {
  

  
  var ooleft = dropZone.offset().left;
  var ooright = dropZone.outerWidth() + ooleft;
  var ootop = dropZone.offset().top;
  var oobottom = dropZone.outerHeight() + ootop;
 
  document.getElementById(dropZoneId).addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    dropZone.addClass(mouseOverClass);
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;

    if (!(x < ooleft || x > ooright || y < ootop || y > oobottom)) {
      inputFile.offset({
        top: y - 15,
        left: x - 100
      });
    } else {
      inputFile.offset({
        top: -400,
        left: -400
      });
    }

  }, true);

  if (buttonId != "") {
    var clickZone = $("#" + buttonId);

    var oleft = clickZone.offset().left;
    var oright = clickZone.outerWidth() + oleft;
    var otop = clickZone.offset().top;
    var obottom = clickZone.outerHeight() + otop;

    $("#" + buttonId).mousemove(function(e) {
      var x = e.pageX;
      var y = e.pageY;
      if (!(x < oleft || x > oright || y < otop || y > obottom)) {
        inputFile.offset({
          top: y - 15,
          left: x - 160
        });
      } else {
        inputFile.offset({
          top: -400,
          left: -400
        });
      }
    });
  }

  document.getElementById(dropZoneId).addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
    $("#" + dropZoneId).removeClass(mouseOverClass);
  }, true);


  inputFile.on('change', function(e) {
    finalFiles = {};
    $('#filename').html("");
    var fileNum = this.files.length,
      initial = 0,
      counter = 0;

    $.each(this.files,function(idx,elm){
       finalFiles[idx]=elm;
    });

    for (initial; initial < fileNum; initial++) {
      counter = counter + 1;
      $('#filename').append('<div id="file_'+ initial +'"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-file fa-stack-1x "></i><strong class="fa-stack-1x" style="color:#FFF; font-size:12px; margin-top:2px;">' + counter + '</strong></span> ' + this.files[initial].name + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-times-circle fa-lg closeBtn" onclick="removeLine(this)" title="remove"></span></div>');
    }
  });



})

function removeLine(obj)
{
  inputFile.val('');
  var jqObj = $(obj);
  var container = jqObj.closest('div');
  var index = container.attr("id").split('_')[1];
  container.remove(); 

  delete finalFiles[index];
  //console.log(finalFiles);
}
```

```css
#drop-zone {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 3px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #7E7E7E;
}
#drop-zone input {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
/*Important*/

#drop-zone.mouse-over {
  border: 3px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: #7E7E7E;
}
/*If you dont want the button*/

#clickHere {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #4679BD;
  padding: 10px;
}
#clickHere:hover {
  background-color: #376199;
}
#filename {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.file-preview {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.closeBtn:hover {
  color: red;
  display:inline-block;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drop-zone">
  <p>Drop files here...</p>
  <div id="clickHere">or click here.. <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple />
  </div>
  <div id='filename'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This JSFiddle exactly implements the function that I was trying to implement. The main issue i was facing was to add an eventlistener to my dynamically generated buttons. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give exact advice without seeing a little more code from your page. If you add elements to your page after page load, then you you won't be able to add an event listener later.

To solve, I would add one more class to each file, then add a listener your file container (I think your container has id "attachedFiles"):

HTML:

```
<div id="attachedFiles">
   <file1 class="attachedfile">
   <file2 class="attachedfile">
   <file3 class="attachedfile">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#attachedFiles').on('click', '.att-file', function() {
    // remove function
}
```

Now any new files that appear within the attachedFiles container will listen for a click and execute your remove function.